# Query regarding JMX

Tags: jmx

Need answers to below two questions:

Q1) Which JMX layer consists of resources

Options:

1.Agent
2.Instrumentation
3.Distributed Services
4.None 
and

Q2) JMX does not contain

Options:

1.Instrumentation
2.Agent
3.management
4.Distributed Services.

Some document enlightening me on these very aspects of JMX will be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The link mentioned in the answer has changed to - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jmxinst/understanding.html

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to : [Understanding JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jmxinst/understanding.html)

You will find out that :

- the JMX layer dealing with resources is the *Instrumentation*
- JMX do not include *Management* (but provides interfaces for clients to implement it)